# Java program evaluating twice

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    public Iterator<IBookItem> findBooksBySeller(String seller) {
        for(int i = 0; i < sellerList.size(); i++){
            if(sellerList.get(i).equals(seller))
            {
                System.out.println("The seller: " + seller + " has the following books for sale: " + titleList.get(i) + " £" + priceList.get(i));
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

            }

        }
        System.out.println("The Seller: " + seller + " has no Books for Sale");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        return null;

    }
```

This is my code and it prints out both statements, could someone pleases tell me why?

Comment: It prints both statements because you never tell it not to. The `for` loop runs, and the conditional must be evaluating to `true`, so that message is printed. Then, then loop finishes, and the very next line prints the second message.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement will be executed if the condition is true for some iteration of the loop. The second statement is always printed after the loop ends (since there's no return statement inside the loop).

You are probably missing a return statement inside your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

At no point are you doing anything to prevent the 2nd group of println's from executing.

You could try adding a `return null;` after your first group of println's.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have excluded the bottom portion of your code from an `else` clause, it will be printed regardless of whether or not the `if` clause is executed. Anything outside of an `if-else` clause is always executed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'return statement' at the end of the 'for' loop.